# UIImageView doesn't refresh (Xcode 8, Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

This is driving me nuts for hours now. I'm writing a simple poker app with 5 cards on the display

```
@IBOutlet weak var card1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var card2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var card3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var card4: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var card5: UIImageView!

var cardMap: [UIImageView] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    deck.shuffle()
    cardMap = [card1, card2, card3, card4, card5]
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is when the user hits the deal button the cards that are not "held" would change to a "plain" card momentarily until new cards are drawn

```
func flipCards(){
    // turn the unheld cards
    for j in 0...4 {
        if heldCards.index(of: j) == nil {
            let plainImage = UIImage(named: "card_plain.jpg")
            self.cardMap[j].image = plainImage
            self.cardMap[j].setNeedsDisplay()

        }
    }

    usleep(useconds_t(300000))
}

@IBAction func deal(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if deck.cards.count < 50 && turn == 1 {
        deck.shuffle()
    }

    self.money.text = String(Int(self.money.text!)! - Int(self.bet.text!)!)

    if turn == 1 {
        currentHand = []
        self.resetHold()
    }

    flipCards()

    for i in 0...4 {
        if turn == 1 || heldCards.index(of: i) == nil {
            if self.turn == 1 {
                self.currentHand.append(self.deck.cards[i])
            } else {
                self.currentHand[i] = self.deck.cards[i]
            }
            self.deck.cards.remove(at: i)
            self.dealSound.play()

            usleep(useconds_t(30000))
            self.currentHand[i].outlet = self.cardMap[i]
            self.currentHand[i].render()


        }
    }

    self.evaluateHand()
    self.cardCount.text = String(deck.cards.count)

}
```

Should be simple enough but for some reason the cards are not flipping to plain before they get re-rendered (currentHand is a list of custom Card object, .render() just replaces the .image on .outlet UIImageView)

I've added a massive usleep to demonstrate that its not a timing issue. I've tested flipCards() by itself and it does what it supposed to do but when it's called in the action's context it has no visual effect. Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: Are you sure the program is going inside this `if heldCards.index(of: j) == nil` condition in those situations when you don't see the cards flipping to plain?

Comment: yes, 100% positive

Comment: For debugging, `print(cardMap[j])` also set `cardMap[j].hidden = true`. Comment out `usleep`. Just make sure you comment out any action after flipping cards.

Comment: @user1046037 thanks for your comment. i've commented out everything after flipCards() and it works as intended. also tried setting the cards hidden and then unhide them but no joy. it seems like the whole view is only drawn at the end of the deal action

Comment: Create a `UIView` animation block to achieve what you intend. Like you had pointed out redrawing of views is optimised, so calling `setNeedsDisplay` every time doesn't guarantee that the view would be redrawn